# How does Java guarantee callback is called when future.isDone() in ListenableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, guava

when going through the [ListenableFutre](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#addListener(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor)) interface, it notes in the doc that

> `addListener()`
>
> Registers a listener to be run on the given executor. The listener
>   will run when the `Future`'s computation is complete or, if the
>   computation is already complete, immediately.`

Since `Future.get()` is a blocking call, how does Java guarantee certain future is Done? are they spinning on this? I understand that with Framework like dagger producers, it is kinda easy to understand (once task is done, write to something, the monitoring thread will be notified). in ListenableFuture case, does jvm support something like this out of box?

using `wait()/notify()` like mechanism ?

---

**FollowUp Question**: as all of you put, it is the caller actually guarantee the listener to be run, normal case to use a `ListenableFuture`
would be `ListenableFuture future = Caller.call()`, with caller and callee in different threads or even in different JVMs, how is this done in java? the listener in stored in both the caller thread and callee thread ? or using remote reigstery when in differnt JVMs?

Comment: Java doesn't guarantee it, nor the JVM either. The provider of the asynchronous service ensures it.

Comment: The ListenableFuture _implementation_ calls the listeners as part of the task.  It is not an external listener waiting on the future.

Comment: Note that `Future.isDone()` is *not* a blocking call, `Future.get()` is.

Comment: @javarookie what counts as a "credible and/or official source" for you? Louis is an active member of the Guava team, I'm a contributor, and I've linked you directly to the implementation of the listener-invoking mechanism. What else do you need, exactly?

Comment: @dimo414, sorry for unclarification, I mistakenly set the bounty with default purpose as "ask for credible source" please ignore it, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, the best way to understand the `ListenableFuture` is to look how it is implemented. When you call `addListener(Runnable listener, Executor exec)`, you provide a `Runnable` listener and an `Executor` to run this listener, so it is you who decides how your listener is executed.

> the listener is stored in both the caller thread and callee thread ?

The listener is stored inside the future, in the `ExecutionList`:

```
// The execution list to hold our executors.
private final ExecutionList executionList = new ExecutionList();
```

And `addListener(Runnable listener, Executor exec)` does just following:

```
public void addListener(Runnable listener, Executor exec) {
    executionList.add(listener, exec);
}
```

So when the future completes, it calls the `set(V value)` method:

```
protected boolean set(@Nullable V value) {
    boolean result = sync.set(value);
    if (result) {
      executionList.execute();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and all listeners are executed like this: `executor.execute(runnable);`

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magic going on with `ListenableFuture` - the contract of the interface simply requires that any implementations invoke any registered listeners upon completion (or immediately, if already done).

It may help to look at one such implementation, [`AbstractFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.java) - specifically look at the [`.complete()` method](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/94116b0/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.java#L835), which is invoked immediately after the future becomes "done" (by finishing, failing, or being cancelled). In order to be both fast and thread-safe the details are somewhat complex, but essentially that's all it does.

Comment: nice point, I have noticed something similar like this, too.  Maybe a good follow up question on this would be:given that listenableFuture usually means something like this,  ListenableFuture result = Caller.call(). usually the caller and callee logic is in different thread, or in different JVM, how is this done in java (if in different jvm, maybe we are using remote registery), how about same jvm, different threads ?

Comment: Your question's not very clear, listeners can only be in the same JVM. You'd need to use some other mechanism to communicate inter-process. As you can see in [`AbstractFuture.complete()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/94116b0/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.java#L867) the listener task is triggered on the `Executor` specified by the listener. Generally speaking this means it will run on a different thread, but the `Executor` API intentionally abstracts that detail away.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add answers.

Guava does not garantee it.
If you down JVM or JVM is crashed no listeners would be invoked.
If you shutdown executor without cancelling futures, no listeners would be invoked too. I mean this case:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(false);
        return t;
    }
});
ListenableFuture<?> listenableFuture = JdkFutureAdapters.listenInPoolThread(
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("run!!!");
            }
        }),
        executorService
);
Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture, new FutureCallback<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@Nullable Object result) {
        System.out.println("onSuccess");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("onFailure");
    }
});
MoreExecutors.shutdownAndAwaitTermination(executorService, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I didn't see "onSuccess" or "onFailure", did you?

In usual workflow when JVM is running, Guava uses [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) to invoke listeners exactly once, you can see it in source code too.